# ¿Cómo enviar y recibir un arreglo a PL/SQL por medio de JavaScript Promises en Oracle Apex?

Tags: javascript, plsql, apex

Actualmente tengo este código en una región que sirve para crear una lista dinámica:

```
    Expediente:
    <input type="text" id="expediente"><p>Expediente agregado: <b id='exp'></b></p>
    <p>Expedientes:</p>
    <ol id="expedientes"></ol>
```

Esto lo tengo en una acción dinámica de un clic en un botón para ir agregando los elementos del input a la lista:

```
    var list = document.getElementById('expedientes');
    
    var firstname = document.getElementById('expediente').value;
    document.getElementById('exp').innerHTML = firstname;
    
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
    list.appendChild(entry);
```

Lo siguiente que hago es intentar enviar los parámetros por medio de Javascript Promises en otra acción dinámica:

```
        var liElems = document.querySelectorAll('ol#expedientes li');
        var liElemsLikeArr = Array.from(liElems);
        var expedientes = "prueba";
        
        liElemsLikeArr.forEach(function(elem) {
          alert(elem.textContent);
        });
    
    console.log(liElemsLikeArr);
    insert();
    
    
    function insert(){
        apex.server.process(
            "CB_AJAX_3",{
                x01: expedientes,
                f10: liElemsLikeArr
            },{
                dataType:"text",
                loadingIndicator:"#P30_RXP_ENC_LABEL",
                success:function(pData){
                    console.log(pData);
                    apex.message.alert(pData);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Por último en una Devolución de Llamada de Ajax intento recibir el arreglo para recorrerlo con un for en PL/SQL:

```
       DECLARE
        l_return varchar2(200);
        var varchar(200);
    BEGIN
    
    for i in 1..apex_application.g_f10.count loop
        var := apex_application.g_f10(i);
    end loop;
    
    l_return := 'Exp: ' || apex_application.g_x01 || ' Array:' || var;
    htp.prn(l_return);
        
    EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        htp.prn('Error');
    END;
```

Como resultado la llamada me devuelve un

Exp: prueba Array:[object HTMLLIElement].

Agradecería mucho su apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo eh solucionado de la siguiente forma:
En primera opte por utilizar un elemento de tipo **Gestor de listas** con valores estáticos en mi vista de Apex:

[image: Gestor de lista]

Lo siguiente fue obtener los valores y asignarlo al arreglo como me mencionaba Monica en su ejemplo, esto por medio de una acción dinámica:

```
var giro = document.getElementById('P28_NEW').value;

var selectedIds = [];

$('select#P28_NEW').find('option').each(function() {
    selectedIds.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(selectedIds.toString());

insert();

function insert(){
    apex.server.process(
        "AJAX_SEND_ARRAY",{
            f10: selectedIds
        },{
            dataType:"text",
            loadingIndicator:"#P28_NEW",
            success:function(pData){
               alert(pData);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Para esto hice uso de las referencias de arreglos donde se deben utilizar como parámetros de envío los siguientes rangos **APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 to APEX_APPLICATION.G_F50** esto en el caso del uso de arreglos.

[Referencia de arreglos](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_app.htm#AEAPI216)

Después de eso recibí el arreglo como ya lo venía haciendo anteriormente:

```
DECLARE
    l_return varchar(200);
    expediente varchar(200);
BEGIN

for i in 1..apex_application.g_f10.count loop
    expediente := expediente || ' ' ||apex_application.g_f10(i);
end loop;

l_return := 'Exp: ' || expediente;
htp.prn(l_return);
    
EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    htp.prn('Error');
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesita utilizar el método **JSON.stringify** en la invocación al proceso Ajax, por ejemplo:
{x01: JSON.stringify(expedientes)},

Haciendo un ejemplo:

```
var selectedIds = [];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {           
          selectedIds.push(i);
        }
```

Y al ejecutar:

```
JSON.stringify(selectedIds);
```

Se obtiene la información del arreglo:
"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]"

Por otro lado, probablemente hay una manera mas sencilla de desarrollar esta solución en APEX.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, ¿de qué otra manera podrías ser?